# Is it yuhara to wear a different tallit pattern?

Tags: tallit-gadol, derech-eretz-manners

Assume that one is davening in a very homogeneous community, would it be yuhara to wear say, an all-white tallit when everyone else wears black-striped ones? Similarly (should I seperate this into another question?) would it be yuhara to wear techeilet when everyone wears all-white?

Comment: Are you possibly confusing Lo sisgodedu with yuhara? Lo sisgodedu is where one is doing something which is different from everyone else. Yuhara is doing something religious for show. That is - when a person is more concerned with his image than he is with the actual religious purpose of what he is doing.

Comment: i stand corrected. From Din online: http://www.dinonline.org/files/newsletter/en_71.pdf the author brings a tshuvas hageonim that states: When the general community is not particular about a certain stringency, a person may not adopt the stringency, thereby demonstrating his 'superiority' to everybody else. "Because others do not refrain from this matter, and he refrains 
from it… it demonstrates yuhara."

Comment: However, this concern for 
yuhara applies only to non-obligatory stringencies. When it comes to a halachic obligation that the general public does not carry out (for whatever reason), a person should not have any concernabout possible arrogance, and must fulfill the obligation irrespective of general practice. This 
principle is mentioned by a number of early authorities concerning the wearing of tefillin (see Ittur, Tefillin), and by the Maharil (Mezuzah 1) concerning affixing mezuzos to all doorways in the house.

Comment: How is the color a Halachik concern?

Comment: @DoubleAA The fabric, probably not. The techeiles (end of this question) is widely believed to be yuhara, though I have not seen this inside (but haven't gone looking either)

Comment: Rav Herschel Schachter holds techeilt is not yuhara